# how to install ubuntu on ubislate 7cz?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have datawind ubislate7cz dual sim tablet, It run on android kitkat os.
this tablet have 512mb ram 2gb internal memory and it is rooted device.
   I want to try ubuntu on this device. It is possible to install ubuntu touch os on ubislate7cz tablet.

thank you.

Comment: The answer is most probably no.